# How do I create a link to a pop up Advanced Custom Fields lighbox gallery?

Tags: wordpress, gallery, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create an Advanced Custom Fields gallery in a lightbox that pops up when an icon is clicked. I've got it to the point where the lightbox finds all the images associated with the post and displays them properly when you click the icon, but the problem I'm having is it's also showing multiple icons for the gallery as well.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTNOs.png)

I assume this is because I have the gallery icon as part of the foreach loop, but I have no idea how to separate it. One idea I had was to simply assign unique CSS classes to the extra icons and then hide them but I was hoping for something more elegant. Can someone point me in the right direction? The code I've cobbled together is below.

```
 <?php 
 $images = get_field('gallery_photos');
 if($images): ?>
    <div class="gallery">   
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" target="_blank" rel="lightbox" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/camera-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="" border="0"/>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, provide visual example like link or SS

Comment: Sorry about that. Site site is on a dev server but I was able to add a screenshot for reference. This shows two sample product rows where one product has a lightbox gallery with 4 images. The lightbox functionality itself works fine, but there should only be one icon for the gallery and when clicked it shows 4 images, not 4 icons that show the 4 images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your loop as below, it will run `img` tag only when `$i=0`, means only first time.

```
<?php 
  $images = get_field('gallery_photos');
    if($images): ?>
      <div class="gallery">   
        <?php $i=0; foreach( $images as $image ) : ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" target="_blank" rel="lightbox" class="thumbnail">
            <?php if( $i==0 ) : ?>
              <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/camera-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="" border="0"/>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </a>
        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the above loop gives the error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()